# android, анимация игральных карт

Tags: android, карты

Мне необходимо реализовать анимацию карт, ее делаю с помощью ConstraintSet. И не понятно, как можно сделать такую анимацию, когда карта переходит из колоды к игроку, то есть чтобы уже имеющиеся карты сдвигались и суммарный вид карт выглядел центрально относительно аватарки игрока. Карты у игрока накладываются друг за другом то есть старт каждой карты зависит от старта предыдущей карты но со сдвигом в 24dp
Примерно, как показано на рисунке ниже
[image: описание положения карт]

Comment: рисунка ниже не наблюдается

Comment: прикреплено изображение того, как они должны выглядеть у игрока